# Changing current user timezone based on server UTC offset and user UTC offset

Tags: php, timezone, utc, datetimeoffset

im writing a twitter web service in php. When a user signs in, i receive this node:

```
<utc_offset>-18000</utc_offset>
```

I have to change the script's timezone so that it adapts to the user's real timezone. The only php function i have found for this is: **[date_default_timezone_set($timezone_identifier)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)** but it won't let me use -18000 as a the $timezone_identifier parameter.

So, how can i change the current user timezone based on two values: **Server UTC offset** and **User UTC offset**

BTW, this is how i'm getting the server UTC offset value:

```
$this_tz_str = date_default_timezone_get();
$this_tz = new DateTimeZone($this_tz_str);
$now = new DateTime("now", $this_tz);
$offset = $this_tz->getOffset($now);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: -18000 is offset not identifier for time zone. For valid timezone identifiers [visit this link](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: i'll use your $usertime instead of time() to calculate dates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get current server time

```
date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

Output for Europe/Paris (my server settings; UTC+2)

```
2011-04-12 20:39:43
```

To get user's time by offset

```
$user_offset = '-18000';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$diff = "$user_offset seconds";
if ((substr($diff,0,1) != '+') && (substr($diff,0,1) != '-')) $diff = '+' . $diff;
$usertime = strtotime($diff, time());
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $usertime);
```

Output UTC-5 (Ecuador -> Quito time NO DST), php timezone identifier `'America/Guayaquil'`.

```
2011-04-12 13:39:43
```

PHP.net manual:

> Timezone offset in seconds. The offset
>   for timezones west of UTC is always
>   negative, and for those east of UTC is
>   always positive. (-43200 through
>   50400)

Comment: thanks for the code, worked great! nice detail on finding out where my timezone was hehe.

Answer (score 1):

The `date_default_timezone...` functions expect a string giving something like "Africa/Luanda" or whatever.

I suggest programmatically searching through the timezone database for a matching offset.  If I recall correctly, those are in minutes from UTC, so you should divide the offset you are given by 60.

Comment: offset is given in seconds... if you divide 18000 by 60 it's 300 hours difference... just not possible UTC-300 :)

Comment: 18000 would be 300 minutes or 5 hours.

Comment: Yes, so you should divide offset by 3600 to get UTC difference in hours UTC-5, right?